# LAB image classification using matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to implement this algorithm, but I am a little confused about the classification of L, A and B . the algorithm outline is as follows:

1. Convert the RGB image to a LAB image.
2. Compute the mean values of the pixels in L, A and B planes of the image
   separately.
3. If mean (A) + mean (B) ≤ 256
   3.1. Classify the pixels with a value in L ≤(mean(L) – standard deviation
   (L)/3) as shadow pixels and others as non-shadow pixels.
4. Else classify the pixels with lower values in both L and B planes as shadow
   pixels and others as non-shadow pixels.

I am very much confused about how to classify L as a shadow pixel and others as non shadow pixels.

This is the code which has the algorithm implemented:

```
clear;
I = imread('flower.jpg');
rgb = imresize(I,[256,256]);
mlab = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab = applycform(rgb,mlab);

S_bin = im2bw(rgb);
S = S_bin + (S_bin == 0);
NS = S;

for i=1:255
     for j=1:255

         A = lab(j,i,2);
         B = lab(j,i,3);
         L = lab(j,i,1);

         Lmean = mean(mean(L));   

         Amean = mean2(mean2(A));
         Bmean = mean2(mean2(B));

         if (Amean + Bmean) <= 256

         Lstd = std2(L);
         std = (Lmean-(Lstd/3));
         Lmean = mean(mean(L));   
            if L <= std
                S(j,i,1) = L;
                S(j,i,2) = L;
                S(j,i,3) = L;
            else
                S = lab;
            end
          else
              if L < B
                 S(j,i,1) = L;
                 S(j,i,2) = L;
                 S(j,i,3) = L;
              else
                 S(j,i,1) = B;
                 S(j,i,2) = B;
                 S(j,i,3) = B;
              end

         end
     end
end    

 S = lab2rgb(S);
 S=uint8(round(S*255));
 figure(3);imshow(S);
```

Comment: How is this related to Matlab? I suspect you want an algorithm in Matlab, but in that case post here the code which you've tried already and point out the exact errors so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `L`, `A` and `B` are scalars. Just one single value. Taking means or standard deviations therefore will not work.

Assign `L`, `A` and `B` first, then take means, standard deviations etc, then built you image in a second loop:

```
I = imread('flower.jpg');
rgb = imresize(I,[256,256]);
mlab = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab = applycform(rgb,mlab);

S_bin = im2bw(rgb);
S = S_bin + (S_bin == 0);
NS = S;

L = squeeze(lab(:,:,1);
A = squeeze(lab(:,:,2);
B = squeeze(lab(:,:,3);

Lmean = mean(L(:));
Amean = mean(A(:));
Bmean = mean(B(:));
Lstd = std(L(:));
Astd = std(A(:));
Bstd = std(B(:));

if (Amean + Bmean) <= 256

if L<=(Lmean-(Lstd/3));    
    tmp = L<=(Lmean-(Lstd/3));    
    S(:,:,1) = zeros(size(L))+L(tmp);
    S(:,:,2) = zeros(size(L))+L(tmp);
    S(:,:,3) = zeros(size(L))+L(tmp);
else
    S = lab;
end
tmp=L<B;
    S(:,:,1) = zeros(size(L))+L(tmp);
    S(:,:,1) = zeros(size(L))+L(tmp);
    S(:,:,1) = zeros(size(L))+L(tmp);
tmp=L=>B;
    S(:,:,1) = zeros(size(B))+B(tmp);
    S(:,:,1) = zeros(size(B))+B(tmp);
    S(:,:,1) = zeros(size(B))+B(tmp);
end

S = lab2rgb(S);
S=uint8(round(S*255));
figure(3);imshow(S);
```

This way you will just get a one colour pane, either coloured according to `L` or `B`, but since you had that before in your code I left it here.

Comment: its still not working.
actually above code is detecting shadow pixels and removing it . it also detecting shadow pixels properly too but when i am trying to remove shadow from image it is not giving me output what i am suppose to

Comment: can i  use svm classification technique for classification of L?

Comment: Probably, but in this case with such a clear criterion you'd better not do that. I'll fix the code in a couple of minutes.